# reading excel files in access vba

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I am trying to read an excel file inside a access application using VBA. I have this code:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWrksht As Excel.worksheet
```

which I got from here:

[Best way to read an Excel file into an Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905512/best-way-to-read-an-excel-file-into-an-access-database)

but when I try to run it, I am getting error that user defines type is not define.

Should  I add a reference to the application?

Is there any way that  can do it without adding a reference to my application?

## Edit 1

After adding reference to the code, Now I have this code:

```
Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
Dim workbook As Excel.workbook
Dim Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Set workbook = excelApp.Open(InputFileName)
Set Worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)
```

But now I am getting error on line:

```
Set workbook = excelApp.Open(InputFileName)
```

as the excelApp doesn't have any method called Open. Should I add any other reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not add a reference to the objects, then Access will not have knowledge of the objects to use with variables.  An object/type is either built-in or referenced so it is usable.

You should also include Excel.Workbook, as the hierarchy is App -> Workbook -> Worksheet -> Cells.

Comment: Thanks, I have a new problem, Can you please help me? I updated the question with new prblem.

Comment: First, you should usually accept the answer to the question asked and open a new question for a different problem.  Second, use workbook.open(InputFileName).

Comment: Specifically: `excelApp.Workbooks.Open(InputFileName)`. Whereas the Application object is not referenced if your ran this line inside Excel, outside you need to reference it (being a foreign object).

Comment: Correct.  I should have been more explicit.

Comment: `Set workbook = excelApp.Application.Workbooks.Open "InputFileName"` Does that do the trick? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

If you know the structure of the Excel worksheet, you can link to various ranges in one worksheet, an treat each of them as a table, using queries and/or Recordsets. Last parameter in this line represents a range in the first worksheet:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, myTableName, ExcelFileName, False, "f3:L10"
```

You remove this link as any table:

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete (myTableName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to your Access project, else it would not recognize it.

G.