# How to read in an excel file to MS Access database and run data validations against it using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, ms-access

I've been reading about many methods that could potentially do this but nothing seems definitive or completely applicative to my situation.

What I want to do is read in an excel file from my desktop (within MS Access VBA) and then while reading it in I want to run a series of data validations against it. Such as check if the cell at B16 is a certain value or if it is a certain string. I need to be able to loop through rows while checking values and summing values. Think of an excel file with a lot of accounting terms and numbers. How would I go about validating that data?

I am currently able to read in excel files and add them to access db tables using:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "MyTbl", _
            Me.txtFileName, True, "Sheet1!"
```

I've also read about using recordsets, using ActiveX Data Objects, and using DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink.

[Import data from Excel into MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428358/import-data-from-excel-into-ms-access)

[Best way to read an Excel file into an Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905512/best-way-to-read-an-excel-file-into-an-access-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "and then while reading it in".  That's not possible to do while DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet is executing.

But you can loop through all rows using Recordset after you have read it in (MyTbl is assumed to be name of table).

Below code loops through each row, column by column:

```
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim f As Field
    
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("sheet1")
    While Not rs.EOF
        For Each f In rs.Fields
            Select Case f.Value
            Case "1234"
                ' do something here when value of column = "1234"
            Case "HelloWorld"
                ' do something here when value of column = "HelloWorld"
            Case Else
                ' do something here when for all other values
                ' for example you could perform a delete here:  rs.Delete
            End Select
        Next
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
    Set rs = Nothing
```

The For Each loop basically lets you iterate through all "columns" of the current "row" of your table.

You reference the value by using f.value above...

The Select Case statements allow to pick specific values.  What you do after is up to you to code!

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain a bit what is happening here? I see a while loop of course, but am not following what "While Not rs.EOF" means or why we have "Debug.print" in there or "Wend and Set rs = Nothing", Will I be able to use this to check individual row values and sum rows together?

Comment: rs.EOF means End Of File, in this specific case, it means end of all rows in your table.  If rs.EOF is true, the while loop will end.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. So basically we are iterating through everything in terms of row by row in "MyTbl" which is just one of many sheets. And so we iterate that Sheet1, why are we using "Debug.print", "Wend" and "Set rs = Nothing". Say I want to check if "B16" in MyTbl is the value 1234 or the string "HelloWorld", how could I do this here?

Comment: Debug.Print is just an example of referencing your field values.  Wend is needed to delimit the While loop.  Set rs = Nothing is just housekeeping to dereference the no longer needed rs recordset object.  If you have a field named "B16", then you can do something like `If (rs.Fields("B16") = "1234" Then 'do something here End.' Or use `Select Case rs.Fields("B16") Case "1234" ' do something here Case "HelloWorld" ' do something here End Select`

Comment: Thanks. I see now that Wend and Set rs = Nothing are basically boiler-plate. So any time we need to reference field values we would use Debug.Print? Does it actually print anything? Also when you say field, are you referring to columns or rows? For "B16" I am talking about the cell B16 inside the excel sheet. I need to be able to iterate row by row, cell by cell checking it and summing things to ensure values and strings.

Comment: I've updated the example code so that it iterates through each column, row by row.